# Identify the interior of a boolean array / blob - NumPy / Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, image-processing

Suppose i have a boolean array with shape (nrows,ncols). True represents that i have a defined value (real number) and False represents an undefined / (not of interest) values.

Im trying to figure out an efficient way to extract the rows and cols of both the boundary and the interior, for example if i had the floowing boolean array, where im marking the boundaries by red and the interior by green:

[image]

then a desired output would be (the position of the green Trues):

**interior = [(2,3), (2,4)]**

We can assume that the interior is always connected.

Using np.where(array == False)[0], i get the indices of the Falses, but how to go from here to the boundaries indices and then to the interior ? I can  ofcourse loop through each boolean and check if any of the neighbours is False, if no, then its an interior.

Any tips on how to do this efficiently without looping? Another example to be clear:

[image]

desired output:
**interior = [(2,3) , (2,4) , (3,3) , (3,4) , (3,5) , (4,3), (4,4), (4,5)]**

The output can be a boolean array as well, containing Trues in interior positions, False otherwise. It does not matter. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

We can use [`2D convolution`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) -

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

def interior_indices(a):
    kernel = np.ones((3,3),dtype=int)
    return np.argwhere(convolve2d(a,kernel,'same')==9)
```

Sample runs -

```
In [44]: a1
Out[44]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False]])

In [45]: interior_indices(a1)
Out[45]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [2, 4]])

In [46]: a2
Out[46]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False]])

In [47]: interior_indices(a2)
Out[47]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [2, 4],
       [3, 3],
       [3, 4],
       [3, 5],
       [4, 3],
       [4, 4],
       [4, 5]])
```

**Approach #2**

Alternatively, with [`uniform-filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.uniform_filter.html) -

```
In [61]: from scipy.ndimage import uniform_filter

In [62]: np.argwhere(uniform_filter(a1,mode='constant'))
Out[62]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [2, 4]])

In [63]: np.argwhere(uniform_filter(a2,mode='constant'))
Out[63]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [2, 4],
       [3, 3],
       [3, 4],
       [3, 5],
       [4, 3],
       [4, 4],
       [4, 5]])
```

**Approach #3**

And with [`binary-erosion`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_erosion.html) -

```
In [72]: from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_erosion

In [73]: kernel = np.ones((3,3),dtype=bool)

In [74]: np.argwhere(binary_erosion(a1,kernel))
Out[74]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [2, 4]])

In [75]: np.argwhere(binary_erosion(a2,kernel))
Out[75]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [2, 4],
       [3, 3],
       [3, 4],
       [3, 5],
       [4, 3],
       [4, 4],
       [4, 5]])
```

Comment: Thats magic to me :) I guess this is much faster than mine since you dont store the 8 matrices during the computation?

Answer (score 1):

Found a way ! If its too trivial, vote delete :)

```
    #data: the boolean array

    d0 = data[1:-1, 2:]
    d1 = data[:-2, 2:]
    d2 = data[:-2, 1:-1]
    d3 = data[:-2, :-2]
    d4 = data[1:-1, :-2]
    d5 = data[2:, :-2]
    d6 = data[2:, 1:-1]
    d7 = data[2:, 2:]


    interior = np.where(d0 & d1 & d2 & d3 & d4 & d5 & d6 & d7, True, False)
```